# What is this mysterious floating menu bar?

Tags: macos

Ever since I upgraded to Mavericks, a mysterious, floating menubar has appeared on my desktop. As you can see from the two screenshots below, it is there when I have many apps open and when I exit as many things as possible. It appears immediately after boot up, and interestingly, when I restart or shut down, it remains visible even after the system leaves the desktop view during the shut down process.

[image: With open apps]
[image: No open apps]

The bar can be moved, but not resized. Right clicking it does nothing.

Any ideas, it is quite annoying, especially when I am not using an external monitor.

Comment: I've seen similar artifacts and I believe - not 100% certain - believe that its a bug caused by running Excel 2011 on Mavericks.

Comment: When you select it(if you can), will it show a different menu in menubar?

Comment: It does not show a different menu in the menubar

Comment: I became very busy after I posted this message and never had the chance to try these suggestions, but through updates, this problem has resolved itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems with applications leaving artefacts on the screen with later versions of OS X. Try to quit also apps in menubar. Download something like magican, or some other program that lets you see what all is running on your mac, check activity monitor for what all is running.

And it may be good to try to relaunch finder (cmd+option+esc, and choose finder, relaunch).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please add download links or similar to the applications you are recommending to make it easier to follow up on your recommendations. I've also removed your follow-up question and added a for this to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Quartz Debug application from [the Apple developer site](http://developer.apple.com/) (free registration) and use it to find which process the window belongs to. Report back with that information if you need help from there.

Comment: Down votes without explanation on posts like this are really annoying—I would have suggested exactly the same; +1